# Is there work on free logic in algebraic logic?

Tags: logic, reference-request, first-order-logic

Has there been work on algebraic versions of [free logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/)?

I've been playing with mechanizing various forms of algebraic logic. I think maybe free logic could simplify some things.

Trivially you can add in an existence predicate and (renaming the original quantifier to $\Sigma$) encode $\exists \kappa. P \equiv \Sigma \kappa. \text{E}(\kappa) \wedge P$ but I feel like you ought to be able to do better.

Consider Cylindrical Algebra. Basically you can think of the existential quantifier as a monad but obviously $ P \vdash \exists \kappa. P $ is a poor fit for free logic. So I think you want rules like $\text{E}(\kappa) \wedge P \rightarrow \exists \kappa. P$. Or possibly you would define $\exists \kappa. P \equiv \text{E}(\kappa) \wedge P$ and $\forall \kappa. P \equiv \text{E}(\kappa) \rightarrow P$ but this seems weird to me.

There's also an odd connection to modal logic I don't get. You can think of quantifiers as collections of modalities indexed by variable names. And I know free logic has a relationship with quantifiers in modal logic. It feels like you ought to be able to use that connection somehow.

Unfortunately algebraic logic is kind of esoteric. I don't need a solution but I would be interested in topics and references to jump off of and explore from here.